# How to get data from MySQL table into Python 2.7

Tags: python, mysql, python-2.7

I want to get data from a MySQL database into Python 2.7. I am using Ubuntu 14.04 and I insert data from Python into MySQL normally, but now I want to receive or get some data from MySQL into Python.

This is my MySQL database:

- database name: `projet`
- table name: `action`

And it was created by this method:

```
create table action(date_time varchar(50) not null,temperature varchar(50),humidity varchar(50));
```

[image]

This is my table `action` who find two values into temperaure and humidity (`ON_1`, `OFF_1`, `ON_2`, `OFF_2`) inserted from a PHP web page.

This image will explain what I said:

[image]

So in first line: `yes=ON_1` and `NO= OFF_1`

and in the second line: `yes= ON_2` and `NO = OFF_2`. The user can type anything.

So I need to get this value into Python.

Comment: I am not sure how much work you put into this. Which library do you use? MySQLdb?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

1st install [MySQLdb](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/MySQL-python/) module or

```
sudo apt-get install python-mysqldb
```

Test the module

```
import MySQLdb
con = MySQLdb.connect(host='localhost', user=username, passwd=password, db=db_name)
cur = con.cursor()
cur.execute("SELECT * FROM YOUR_TABLE_NAME")

# print all the first cell of all the rows
for row in cur.fetchall():
    print row[0]

con.close()
```